# Destructuring object with a converter

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Say, I have an object

```
const range = { min: '10', max: '20' }
```

And I want to destructure it so that after that I have 2 variables:
 - `min` with the value of `10` (not `string '10'`), and
 - `max` with the value of `20`

`const { min, max } = range` will only result to `min` with the value of `'10'` (not `10`). What I want is the `Number(10)`

How could I do that? I did know a little bit about ES6 destructuring and did some research, tried different syntaxes but couldn't find a satisfied solution. Could anyone suggest one?

**Conclude**: There're very nice clever syntax in the answers below, but as to go with real code, I would just go with the more verbose but readable one:

```js
const min = +range.min // or Number(range.min)
const max = -range.max // or Number(range.max)
```

Comment: Not sure you can apply a function on that, destructuring is only assigning an object/array to a range of variables

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use two extra variable with `+min` and `+max` as default value,

```js
const range = { min: '10', max: '20' }

const {min, max, numMin = +min, numMax = +max} = range

console.log(numMin, numMax)
```

***Note:-*** here in above method make sure you use names for extra variable which are not available in object, else it won't use the default value

---

Another way is to use `IIFE`, transform the object values to numeric values before destructuring

```js
const range = { min: '10', max: '20' }

const {min,max} = ( ({min,max}) => ( {min: +min, max: +max} ) )(range)

console.log(min,max)
```

---

In practical purpose or actual code i will not use such tricky ways because i prefer readability and it has it's own benefits

```js
const range = {
  min: '10',
  max: '20'
}

const min = parseInt(range.min)
const max = parseInt(range.max)

console.log(max, min)
```

Comment: I like the 2nd one

Comment: I like the 1st one ~

Comment: In practical use i won't use any of them, i will simply define two variable and parse the values as number,i.e `const min = parseInt(obj.min)`

Comment: @CodeManiac yet that's what I'll do. I expected some syntax just simple like `const { min, max }:Number = range` or `const Number{ min, max } = range`. Unless, I'll just go with defining 2 variables.

Answer (score 5):

You could take the destructured values in an array and destructure the mapped values again.

```js
var range = { min: '10', max: '20' },
    { min, max } = range;        

[min, max] = [min, max].map(Number);

console.log(typeof min, min);
console.log(typeof max, max);
```

Comment: Thank you, I do like this one but will just end up using `const min = Number(range.min); const max = Number(range.max);` in my code for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do any conversion as part of a de-structuring operation, but you could try to do a transformation first.

If you had a function like this:

```
function parseKeys(obj) {
    const parsed = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        try {
            parsed[key] = parseInt(obj[key]);
        } catch () {}
    }

    return { ...obj, ...parsed };
}
```

Then you could have a one-liner like this:

```
const { min, max } = parseKeys(range);
```